# OrientDB in AWS with auto load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, orientdb

In AWS, I have a single persistent node with a static IP.
I can have any number of nodes that can join via an auto scaling group. 
I have a load balancer that routes to port 2480 and 2424.

When the nodes come online, they join perfectly to hazelcast. When I query the database via my browser, I can see the result come from various nodes so I know hazelcast is working.

My Application however can't seem to connect via port 2424 on the load balancer. The connection dies on all nodes but the browser can still communicate with the DB via port 2480.

I'm using rabbitmq with celery to handle my tasks but it's difficult to debug what's happening. Celery keeps timing out and it's not that the connection is refused, it just hangs with no error. Sometimes the connection succeeds without problems but dies within a couple of requests.

I have the ports open on the security groups so I have no idea what could be causing the disconnect. Here is my hazelcast config:

```
<hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
            <name>my_network</name>
            <password>secret</password>
    </group>
    <properties>
            <property name="hazelcast.local.localAddress">172.31.44.109</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.mancenter.enabled">false</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.memcache.enabled">false</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.rest.enabled">false</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.wait.seconds.before.join">5</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.operation.thread.count">1</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.operation.generic.thread.count">1</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.client.event.thread.count">1</property>
            <property name="hazelcast.event.thread.count">1</property>
    </properties>
    <network>
            <public-address>89.19.11.180</public-address>
            <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">2434</port>
            <join>
                    <multicast enabled="false">
                            <multicast-group>235.1.1.1</multicast-group>
                            <multicast-port>2434</multicast-port>
                            <multicast-timeout-seconds>5</multicast-timeout-seconds>
                    </multicast>
                    <aws enabled="false">
                            <access-key>accesskey</access-key>
                            <secret-key>secret</secret-key>
                            <region>eu-west-1</region>
                            <security-group-name>my-security-group</security-group-name>
                    </aws>
                    <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                            <required-member>89.19.11.185</required-member>
                            <member>89.19.11.180</member>
                    </tcp-ip>
            </join>
    </network>
    <executor-service>
            <pool-size>16</pool-size>
    </executor-service>
</hazelcast>
```

I did try to use the  setup but it wasn't working. The nodes could not connect to one another.

works but because I only have 1 known IP, that node acts as the master node.

Why does connections to the DB on port 2424 fail? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the stupid question, but are you sure that the ELB is in TCP for port 2424 and not in HTTP? Eventually can you paste the given error?

Tnks

Comment: I've tracked the issue down to pyorient getting stuck in an infinite loop when connecting on port 2424 while in distributed mode and hazelcast not liking my public ip addresses.